# What do we mean by this code if written in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle

If I write the following code for example in 'Gemfile':

```
group :development do
gem 'xyz'
end

group:test do
gem 'xyz'
end
```

What does that mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify which gems should be installed in which environment. For example, you might wanna use SQLite for development and testing, but MySQL on production. So you would write:

```
gem 'devise'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite'
end

group :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Running `bundle install --without development:test` will install devise and mysql2 gems.

Answer (score 3):

Only install the `xyz` gem in the development and test environments.

It can also be written as:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'xyz'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It means that all those gems in blocks will be loaded only in this environmets (test or development)